# how to solve $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-13}}\text{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry, substitution

As the question says, I am trying to solve $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-13}}\text{d}x$

Here is what I have so far:

$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-13}}\text{d}x$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}} \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{13}-1}} \text{d}x$

$u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{13}}$

$\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}*\sqrt{13} \int \frac{13u^2}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\text{d}u$

**I got the $13u^2$ by setting $\sqrt{13}u = x$ and squaring both sides**

$13 \int \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\text{d}u$

$u = \sec(\theta)$

$\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}\theta} = \sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)$

$13 \int \frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{\tan(\theta)}*\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)\text{d}\theta$

$13 \int \sec^3(\theta)\text{d}\theta$

*This is the point where I am stuck at*

*Also, I just started learning trig substitution so if there is an easier way to do this please tell me. Thank you*

Comment: There's probably a recursion,  gotten from integration by parts.

Comment: Integrate by parts using $\sec^{2}\theta d\theta = d\left(\tan \theta\right)$

Comment: @Voltagecrayon24 FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%5Csec%5E3(%5Ctheta)d%5Ctheta%24&p=1), the end part of this [answer](/a/1187453) and the AoPS thread's [integral Post #$2$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1323507p7140118) both deal with how to solve $\int\sec^3(\theta)d\theta$.

Comment: On the other hand,   $x = \sqrt{13}  \cosh t$   works out nicely

Comment: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_15/hyperbolic.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$   x = \sqrt{13}  \cosh t \; , \; \; \; dx = \sqrt{13}  \sinh t   dt  $$
$$  \sqrt{x^2 - 13} = \sqrt{13 \cosh^2 t - 13 } = \sqrt {13}  \sqrt{\cosh^2 t - 1}  =   \sqrt {13}  \sinh t $$

$$ \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 - 13}}  dx =  13 \int  \cosh^2 t dt = 13 \int \frac{1}{2}  + \frac{1}{2} \,\cosh 2t \, dt   $$

$$ \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 - 13}}  dx = C +  13 \left(   \frac{t}{2}  + \frac{1}{4} \,\sinh 2t\right)  $$

now we need to express  $t$  and $\sinh 2t $   in terms of $x$

I guess the quickest way comes from $ \cosh t + \sinh t = e^t$ So

$$ \sqrt{13 }e^t  =  x + \sqrt{x^2 - 13}   $$

Also
$$     x \, \sqrt{x^2 - 13}  = 13 \sinh t \cosh t   $$
$$    2 x \, \sqrt{x^2 - 13}  = 13 \sinh 2t    $$

Comment: Good chance that OP's in a calculus class and OP hasn't learned hyperbolic trig. I do agree that hyperbolic trig makes things quite simple sometimes, like $\int \sqrt{1+x^2} dx$ which also results in $\int \sec^3(u) du$ with tan substitution

Comment: @gist076923 You would be correct. However, I am very much struggling with this concept. Do you know any good resources to learn hyperbolic functions? I consider myself to be a quick learner so I hope it will not take long.

Comment: @gist076923 Also, I don't know many trig identities(Such as the double-angle ones). I am well aware that a simple search on google could get me a whole list, but I want to under the reasoning behind these identities. If you have any resources, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Voltagecrayon24  try https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_15/hyperbolic.pdf .

Comment: @Voltagecrayon24  good. I would have put another few relevant formulas before the examples of integration. If you have a way to typeset (similar to the MathJax here)  suggest you work up your own one-page  summary of useful hyperbolic things. You could put that as an answer here, edit in stuff you might find elsewhere. Print out a screenshot... I would include the version of the Weierstrass half angle substitution  for hyperbolic trig.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Hyperbolic_functions   Worth your effort

Comment: @WillJagy Okay. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we deal with the integral by integration by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int x^2 d\left(\sqrt{x^2-13}\right) \\
& =x \sqrt{x^2-13}-\int \sqrt{x^2-13}\ d x\\&= x \sqrt{x^2-13}-\int \frac{x^2-13}{\sqrt{x^2-13}} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Rearranging yields

$$
I=\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{x^2-13}+\frac{13}{2} \int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{x^2-13}}
$$

Using the substitution $x=\sqrt 13 \sec \theta $, we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{x^2-13}} & =\int \sec \theta d \theta \\
& =\ln |\sec \theta+\tan \theta|+c_1 \\ &= \ln \left|x+\sqrt{x^2-13}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $$
I=\frac{1}{2}\left[x \sqrt{x^2-13}+13 \ln \left|x+\sqrt{x^2-13}\right|\right]+C
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let's try integration by parts: $$\int\sec^3\theta =\tan\theta \sec\theta-\int\sec\theta\tan^2\theta=\tan\theta\sec\theta-\int(\sec^3\theta-\sec\theta)\implies \int\sec^3\theta =\dfrac 12(\tan\theta \sec\theta +\int\sec\theta ).$$

Answer (score 0):

$sec^3(\theta)=\frac{1}{cos^3(\theta)}=\frac{cos(\theta)}{cos^4(\theta)}=\frac{cos(\theta)}{(1-sin^2(\theta))^2}$.

Take $t=sin(\theta)$, then $$I=\int \frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-t+1+t}{(1-t)^2(1+t)^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{(1-t)(1+t)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-t)^2(1+t)})=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1-t+1+t}{(1-t)(1+t)^2}+\frac{1-t+1+t}{(1-t)^2(1+t)})=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}+\frac{2}{(1-t)(1+t)}+\frac{1}{(1-t)^2})=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}+\frac{1-t+1+t}{(1-t)(1+t)}+\frac{1}{(1-t)^2})=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-t)}+\frac{1}{(1+t)}+\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}) $$
Hence, $$I=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{1-t}-\frac{1}{1+t}+ln(1+t)-ln(t-1))$$